# The order of Omega subgroup in abelian $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was working through one lemma and it's corollary from Herstein's book and I am not able to grasp one moment.

[image]

The author writes that $t=k$ but it is not obvious to me. Can anyone explain it, please?

Comment: I think this is a mistake. It is not necessarily the case that $t=k$, because we could have $n_j=1$ for some $j$. But in any case, when $m=1$, all of the subgroups $B_i$ and also all of the subgroups $A_j$ with $j>t$ have order $p$, so $o(G(p)) = p^k$, and the result in the corollary is correct.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Thanks I got it!